# Help with method(s) show an iterative method converges to a known fixed point

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, statistical-inference

Are there any general techniques that can be used to show that an iterative method converges to a (known) fixed point?. In my current situation, I know the exact fixed point, but I am unaware of a method to show that the algorithm will converge to the point with certainty.

If it helps, I am using the EM algorithm and am trying to show that the algorithm converges to the true (known in this case) MLE.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You seem to be conflating a convergence of a fixed-point iteration, usually amenable to analysis of contraction map properties, with narrowing of confidence intervals for parameter estimation.  In any case the specific details of what you are doing seem crucial to providing specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't converge to the fixed point with certainty. The answer depends on the starting point. For a multi-modal distribution, it can converge to any local maximum. The general proof involves coupling co-ordinate ascent with strong duality. Check out the link below

http://web.stanford.edu/~lmackey/stats306b/doc/stats306b-spring14-lecture3_scribed.pdf